# Can one retrieve the Windows Standby Timer?

Tags: c++, windows

Is the Windows standby timer available?  How can I retrieve it using c++?

Comment: Does "windows standby timer" refer to the hardware battery operated clock?

Comment: I want the working version of the standby timer as defined in the power options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need CallNtPowerInformation, passing SystemPowerInformation.  The returned SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION.TimeRemaining ought to be relevant.

Comment: Yes this looks like it.  Well found.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetCurrentPowerPolicies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372689%28VS.85%29.aspx) - within the returned [USER_POWER_POLICY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373239%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) there are idle timeouts for DC and AC power situations.  You can check which applies using [GetSystemPowerStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372693%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: These look like config parameters, not working ones.  I'm interested in time remaining b4 standby starts.